# Java android Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?

Tags: java, android

I want to displey a text in TextView :
 this is my value in string :

```
<string name="coords2">Lat: %1$.2f %c\nLon: %2$.2f\n(%3$.0fm)</string>
```

But when I build a apk I see this :

```
Error:(764) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
Error:(764) Unexpected end tag string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello You can print that characters using this

```
 TextView tvIn;
 String spcialCharacter="Lat: %1$.2f %c\\nLon: %2$.2f\\n(%3$.0fm)";
 tvIn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvIn);
 tvIn.setText(Html.fromHtml(spcialCharacter));
```